# highlight only one button at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to highlight only one button at once, so the others reset to original color once a new one is clicked. What do I need to add to my JavaScript to make this happen?

This is a classroom on repl.IT.
My classroom task is:

1. Put styles for the `btn-highlight` class in the index.css file.
2. Put a handler for click default button (class `btn-default`) in the index.js file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-default").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-highlight");
  }); // Put your code here
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* styles for highlighted buttons */

.btn-highlight,
.btn-highlight:focus,
.btn-highlight:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  /* Put styles here */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sign-in">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="0">
                  Button 0
                </button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="1">
                  Button 1
                </button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="2">
                  Button 2
                </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `$(".btn-highlight").toggleClass('.btn-default')` to turn it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make you CSS more specific in order to be able to apply the background. Then in the jQuery code you can simply remove the class from all the button and then add it to the current button, so that only one have it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-default").click(function() {
    $(".btn-default").removeClass('btn-highlight')
    $(this).addClass("btn-highlight");
  }); // Put your code here
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}


/* styles for highlighted buttons */

.btn-default.btn-highlight,
.btn-default.btn-highlight:focus,
.btn-default.btn-highlight:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  /* Put styles here */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sign-in">Sign in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p>
          <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="0">
                  Button 0
                </button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p>
          <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="1">
                  Button 1
                </button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p>
          <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="2">
                  Button 2
                </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- /container -->


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

CSS
```